# Drawing a Quantile Plot

Tags: r, plot

I have fitted a quantile regression model in the code below.
Now I am trying to plot this as multiple Quantile Regression Plots,
one for each variable. Can someone please help me.

Quantile Regression

```
Clouds.Formula <- rainfall ~ seeding +
  seeding: (sne + cloudcover + prewetness + echomotion) + time

Clouds.Quantile <- rq(Clouds.Formula, data = clouds, tau = 0.5)
summary(Clouds.Quantile)
Clouds.Quant.Coeff <- coef(Clouds.Quantile)
residuals(Clouds.Quantile)
fitted(Clouds.Quantile)
```

Here's my code for the plot that just wont work.

```
QR <- rq(Clouds.Quantile, tau = seq(0.2, 0.8, by = 0.1))
QR.Plot <- summary(QR)
```

Here's the kind of plot I am trying to graph

[image]

Comment: `plot(QR.Plot)` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
QR <- rq(Clouds.Formula, data = clouds, tau = seq(0.2, 0.8, by = 0.2))

QR.Plot <- summary(QR)

plot(QR.Plot, xlim=c(0.001,10), ylim=c(0.001,10), log="xy")
```

I checked and it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked. Now the error I had been getting is making sense too.

Comment: you are welcome soly. I though you will give me vote up, if this worked for you :) hahaha. anyways. good luck.